# Changing the context root of an application

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I have two servers (dev1 and dev2) an application with context root **app** is hosted on both these servers i can access these application by thier url e.g.

```
http://dev1:8080/app
http://dev2:8080/app
```

so want is

```
 http://dev1/app1 redirect to dev1 app   
 http://dev1/app2 redirect to dev2 app
```

i have apache 2.2 installed on dev1 server and tried the following

**httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
     RewriteEngine On
     JkOptions +ForwardURICompat
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)app1(.*)$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)app1(.*)$  $1app$2 [PT,L]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)app2(.*)$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)app2(.*)$  $1app$2    [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

**worker.properties**

```
worker.list=node1,node2

worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.host=dev1
worker.node1.port=8009


worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.host=dev2
worker.node2.port=8009
```

**mod_jk.conf**

```
JkMount /app1/ node1
JkMount /app1/* node1

JkMount /app2/ node2
JkMount /app2/* node2
```

**EDIT**:
redirect is working now but all the application url are now redirecting to

http://dev1/app instead of (http://dev1/app1 or http://dev1/app2)

Comment: You should be matching `%{HTTP_HOST}` with `dev1` or `dev2`

Comment: @hjpotter92 can u please give me an example

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app1$` should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev1$`

Comment: @hjpotter92 see the updated question